# How do I add an evaluated scan object into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I want to scan 20 integers from the user. Once the user enters a negative value, the scan stops.

After that, how can I add the positive values that the user entered into an array?

```
System.out.println("\nEnter up to 20 non-negative numbers:");

for(i = 0; i <= list20.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Number " + (i+1) + ": ");
    input = scan.nextInt();

    if(input > 0) { 
        input = input.list20[i] // How to add positive integer here??
    }
    else
    break;
}
```

Comment: list20[i]=input; and change <= to <

Comment: You need to wait until you've finished getting your input, then add up the values you've collected.

Comment: Clarification: are you intending to allow the user to enter 0 (which technically is a non-negative number)?

Comment: `input.list20[i] = input`

Comment: What is this `input.list20[]`? Isn't `input` an `int`?

Comment: @Jason: Sorry, I didn't understand you. 0 is a non-negative number yes. The question on my assignment specifically states " Your program should have a loop that reads the integers into an array and stops when a negative value in entered" So 0 should be positive! Regarding the  "input.list20[]" , I was trying to get the input into the list20 array.

Comment: `input.list20[i]` is not valid Java in this context, given that `input` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// first, zero out the array using whatever method you want
for(i = 0; i < list20.length; i++)
{
    list20[i] = 0;
}

// then request the values
System.out.println("\nEnter up to 20 non-negative numbers:");
for(i = 0; i < list20.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Number "+ (i+1) + ": ");
    input = scan.nextInt();

    if(input>=0)
    { 
        list20[i] = input;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

// then total the non-negative values
int total = 0;
if(i >= 20) {
    for(int value : list20)
    {
        if(value > 0) {
            total += value;
        }
    }
}
```